# Removing a part of a string without using substr

Tags: php, string, substr

I have a string with a different variety of strings of different lengths

**Example:**

```
/my-big-property/Residential/Sections-for-sale 

/my-big-property/Residential/for-sale
```

I am wanting to only remove `/my-big-property/` but because `substr` does not seem to work what other options do I have?

Comment: A regex would be simplest, str_replace, or a whacky explode workaround if the path part positions are fixed. How does your substr test code look?

Comment: @mario they are fixed how would I do the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain further by `substr` doesn't work? This seems like an awfully simple problem.

```
<?php
$a = "/my-big-property/Residential/Sections-for-sale";
$b = substr($a, 17);
echo $b;
```

If the initial string between the first `/` and second `/` is variable, then regex such as this would suffice:

```
<?php
$a = "/my-big-property/Residential/Sections-for-sale";
preg_match("/\/\S+?\/(.*)/", $a, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /my-big-property/Residential/Sections-for-sale
    [1] => Residential/Sections-for-sale
)
```

Answer (score 0):

substr is working fine, you are just not using it properly. It is a function not a procedure.
It does not change the original string but returns a new substring.

Answer (score 0):

Above all the suggested solutions which are correct you can simply use the following:

```
$string="/my-big-property/Residential/Sections-for-sale";

$string = str_replace("/my-big-property/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $a = "/my-big-property/Residential/Sections-for-sale";
    $temp = explode('/my-big-property/',$a);
    $temp_ans = $temp[1];
    echo $temp_ans;
?>
```

There will be two array one will be blank and another will have desired value.